# Using ArcPy to get length of Polyline created?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, line, length, typeerror

I am trying to get the length of Polylines I am creating immediately after I create them.

The code I am using:

```
arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(firstx, firsty), arcpy.Point(secondx, secondy)])).getLength('GEODESIC', 'METERS')
```

Error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Josh\Scripts\Projects\carriageways_unplit_ptSplit.py", line 53, in <module>
    road_specs['{0}_{1}_{2}'.format(round(road[0], 5), round(road[1], 5), arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(firstx, firsty), arcpy.Point(secondx, secondy)])).getLength('GEODESIC', 'METERS'))] = road[2]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 781, in getLength
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.GetLength(*gp_fixargs((method, units))))
TypeError: Invalid geometry type for method
```

Am I creating the polyline incorrectly?

Comment: Spatial reference part is missing in Polyline()

Comment: That's not a required parameter though. Do you think it is saying that it doesn't know how to draw it because of the reference?

Comment: @FelixIP Could you write that as the answer, so I can mark you? It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spatial reference of newly created Polyline is undefined, this is why ArcGis struggles with next request, that is a calculation of geodetic length.

So, define spatial reference in arcpy. Polyline () method. I also suggest to split single line of code into three a) create array of points b) create Polyline c) calculate it's length. This is easier to read and debug